# Creating a reusable template in knockout

Tags: mvvm, knockout.js

I have created a number of templates in knockout that essentially act as controls on a page.  As an example a simple control to select from a group of values looks like:

```
 <div data-bind="foreach: values">
      <div data-bind="css: { selectedItem: $parent.value() == $data.value }, event: { click: function () { $parent.value($data.value) } }">
           <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
      </div>
 </div>
```

I would like to re-use this template across multiple properties on a single view model, but at the moment I can't see how, as the bindings are "hard-coded", i.e. it will always been looking for a values property, and a name property etc.

I know the foreach binding has the "as" alias option, is there anything similar where I can provide aliases for a number of properties to a template?  Or is there a better way to tackle this?

At the moment I have an intermediate viewmodel which takes the values, value and name property in the constructor and then uses that for bindings, but it feels unnecessarily complex to me.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine to template and foreach techniques to achieve the result you need

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html  ( See Note 3 )

Without knowing the remainder of your view models / html, the following should give an idea of how it works

```
<script type="text/html" id="name-set">
  <div data-bind="css: { selectedItem: $parent.value() == $data.value }, event: { click: function () { $parent.value($data.value) } }">
       <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
  </div>
</script>

<div data-bind="template: { name: 'name-set', foreach: values }"></div>
```

Comment: Hi Robert, the template I showed was just an example, others I use are more complex than could be handled using a foreach.  My question was more along the lines of being able to supply a group of aliases to a template in order to reuse more easily.